# how to add space between nodes in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

I have the following tikz picture:

```
 \documentclass{book}
 \usepackage{tikz}

 \begin{document}

 \begin{tikzpicture}
 \node(x1) {$x_1$};
 \node(x2) [right of = x1] {$x_2$};
 \node(x3) [right of = x2]{$x_3$};
 \node(x4) [right of = x3]{$x_4$};

 \draw [->] (x1) -- (x2) ;
 \draw [->] (x2) -- (x3) ;
 \draw [->] (x3) -- (x4) ;


 \node(y1) [below of = x1]{$y_1$};
 \node(y2) [right of = y1] {$y_2$};
 \node(y3) [right of = y2] {$y_3$};
 \node(y4) [right of = y3] {$y_4$};

 \draw [->] (y1) -- (x1) ;
 \draw [->] (y2) -- (x2) ;
 \draw [->] (y3) -- (x3) ;
 \draw [->] (y4) -- (x4) ;

 \end{tikzpicture}

  \end{document}
```

I want the arrows to be longer. When I use "shorten >= -5pt" for example, in the draw command in the square brackets, the arrows become longer, but they go over the nodes. Is there a way to make everything more spacious, in addition to lengthening the arrows?

Also, is there a way to insert another node to the left of one of the vertical arrows? (or more specifically, how do I state "below of" or "left of" etc. for an arrow, and not a node?) I tried \draw(arr1) to label the arrow, and then later put a node to the left of arr1, but I get an error.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You shouldn't use `below of = node`. It is deprecated (see [Difference between "right of=" and "right=of" in PGF/TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9386/difference-between-right-of-and-right-of-in-pgf-tikz)). Instead use the `positioning` library from tikz. It allows you to write `right = 1.5cm of node`. You may vary or leave out the distance.

To label a path, just add `node[left] {label 1}` behind the `--`. You may add `pos=value` with a value between 0 and 1 to the node options to specify the position on the path.

### Example

(your modified code)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node(x1) {$x_1$};
        \node(x2) [right = 1.5cm of x1] {$x_2$};
        \node(x3) [right = 1.5cm of x2]{$x_3$};
        \node(x4) [right = 1.5cm of x3]{$x_4$};

        \draw [->] (x1) -- (x2) ;
        \draw [->] (x2) -- (x3) ;
        \draw [->] (x3) -- (x4) ;


        \node(y1) [below = 2 of x1]{$y_1$};
        \node(y2) [below = 2 of x2] {$y_2$};
        \node(y3) [below = 2 of x3] {$y_3$};
        \node(y4) [below = 2 of x4] {$y_4$};

        \draw [->] (y1) -- node[left, pos=0.2] {beginning} (x1) ;
        \draw [->] (y2) -- node[left, pos=.8] {ending} (x2) ;
        \draw [->] (y3) -- node[left] {label 3} (x3) ;
        \draw [->] (y4) -- node[left] {label 4} (x4) ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Results in:

[image: result]

Answer (score 5):

## Remarks

You can specify the default distance between node, which are placed using `right of=`, `left of=`, etc using the key `node distance=<length>`.

To place a node along a path, just insert it after the lineto-operation, i.e.

```
\draw (0,0) -- node {on the path} (4,0);
```

If you want the text to be sloped with your path, use the `sloped` key as an option to the node.

Read more about node placement in the [TikZ Documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf) in section 16.8 on page 190.
You might also be interested in the Tutorial "A Petri-Net for Hagen", which investigates in nodes and can be found in chapter 3 on page 40.

## Implementation

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2.5cm]
    \node(x1) {$x_1$};
    \node(x2) [right of = x1] {$x_2$};
    \node(x3) [right of = x2] {$x_3$};
    \node(x4) [right of = x3] {$x_4$};

    \draw [->] (x1) -- (x2) ;
    \draw [->] (x2) -- (x3) ;
    \draw [->] (x3) -- (x4) ;


    \node(y1) [below of = x1]{$y_1$};
    \node(y2) [right of = y1] {$y_2$};
    \node(y3) [right of = y2] {$y_3$};
    \node(y4) [right of = y3] {$y_4$};

    \draw [->] (y1) -- node[sloped,below] {(y1) $\to$ (x1)} (x1) ;
    \draw [->] (y2) -- node[sloped,below] {(y2) $\to$ (x2)} (x2) ;
    \draw [->] (y3) -- node[sloped,below] {(y3) $\to$ (x3)} (x3) ;
    \draw [->] (y4) -- node[sloped,below] {(y4) $\to$ (x4)} (x4) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## Output

> [image]